# Group dates where difference between end_date and next start_date less than 2 minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table with tasks description and I need populate table with grouped tasks:

Main table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tasks](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [task_id] [int] NULL,
    [task_start_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [task_end_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [duration_sec] [int] NULL,
    [owner_name] [varchar](150) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
```

Data:

```
insert into tasks
values
 (1125, '2022-06-09 14:56:58',  '2022-06-09 15:02:26',  328,        'John Parsons')
,(1126, '2022-06-09 15:03:43',  '2022-06-09 15:33:50',  1807,       'John Parsons')
,(1127, '2022-06-09 15:34:55',  '2022-06-09 16:05:02',  1807,       NULL)
,(1128, '2022-06-09 16:06:06',  '2022-06-09 16:21:03',  897,        'John Parsons')
,(1129, '2022-06-09 16:39:56',  '2022-06-09 16:47:34',  458,        'Sarah Mitchell')
,(1129, '2022-06-09 16:50:57',  '2022-06-09 16:55:59',  302,        'Sarah Mitchell')
,(1130, '2022-06-09 17:11:26',  '2022-06-09 17:24:07',  761,        'John Parsons')
,(1131, '2022-06-10 21:11:34',  '2022-06-10 21:23:21',  707,        'Sarah Mitchell')
,(1131, '2022-06-10 21:24:35',  '2022-06-10 21:39:37',  902,        'Sarah Mitchell')
,(1132, '2022-06-10 21:45:37',  '2022-06-10 23:02:05',  4588,       NULL)
```

Target table:

```
create table dbo.grouped_tasks(
id int identity (1,1) primary key
,task_id int
,task_start_date datetime
,task_end_date datetime
,duration_sec int
,break_duration int
,owner_name varchar(150)
)
```

Expected result:

```
insert into grouped_tasks
values
(1125   ,'2022-06-09 14:56:58', '2022-06-09 16:21:03',  5045    ,206,   'John Parsons')
,(1129  ,'2022-06-09 16:39:56', '2022-06-09 16:47:34',  458     ,0, 'Sarah Mitchell')
,(1129  ,'2022-06-09 16:50:57', '2022-06-09 16:55:59',  302     ,0, 'Sarah Mitchell')
,(1130  ,'2022-06-09 17:11:26', '2022-06-09 17:24:07',  761     ,0, 'John Parsons')
,(1131  ,'2022-06-10 21:11:34', '2022-06-10 21:39:37',  1683    ,74,    'Sarah Mitchell')
,(1132  ,'2022-06-10 21:45:37', '2022-06-10 23:02:05',  4588    ,0, NULL)
```

I'm trying to populate groups of tasks. When date diff between end_date and next start_date is <= 120 seconds I should group it and select min(task_id), min(task_start_date) and max(task_end_date), sum(duration), sum(break_duration).
I calculated in cte lead values and datediff between end and lead value but I have wrong results, I don't know how to group that values to get min and max dates

```
drop table if exists #temp

select  
       task_id
      ,lead(task_id) over (order by task_start_date) next_task
      ,task_start_date
      ,task_end_date
      ,lead(task_start_date)  over (order by task_start_date) next_start
      ,datediff(second,task_end_date, lead(task_start_date)  over (order by task_start_date)) date_diff
      ,duration_sec
      ,owner_name
  into #temp
  from dbo.tasks

  with cte as (select * from #temp
  where date_diff <=120)
  select distinct  c.*, t.task_id, t.task_end_date as for_max_end_date from cte c
  left join #temp t on c.next_task = t.task_id
  where c.next_task <> c.task_id
```

result:
[image]

Here is the desired output I am trying to get:

[image]

Comment: What's "wrong results" look like? Include your query so we can see what you are trying to do and point out any issues. Include desired results as text, not as an image.

Comment: I do not understand what do you want. Have you checked the results you get when you calculate datediff? You expect to get 1129 back and its datediff is 203 and 927 ?? Check your data pls and then recreate the question and try to be as simple and as accurate as possible. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5737cdf9446bb8d1599baf176488a689

Answer (score 0):

use window function `LAG` to get previous row `task_end_date` (order by `task_start_date`) and compare with `task_start_date`. When it is more than 120 secs, return a indicator. Apply cumulative `sum` on it and that forms your required grouping.

```
with
cte1 as
(
    select *,
           g = case when datediff(second,
                                  lag(task_end_date) over (order by task_start_date),
                                  task_start_date) > 120
                    then 1
                    else 0
                    end
    from  tasks t
),
cte2 as
(
    select *,
           break_duration = case when g = 0 
                                 then datediff(second,
                                               lag(task_end_date) over (order by task_start_date),
                                               task_start_date) 
                                 else 0 
                                 end,
            grp  = sum(g) over(order by task_start_date)
    from  cte1
)
select task_id         = min(task_id),
       task_start_date = min(task_start_date),
       task_end_date   = max(task_end_date),
       duration_sec    = sum(duration_sec),
       break_duration  = sum(break_duration),
       owner_name      = max(owner_name)
from   cte2
group by grp
```